# How can i change a picklist to a multiselect picklist

Tags: metadata

It seems like the only way to do this for a field thats already in a live salesforce is to

1. Export all the data from that object/field
2. Comment out any code (including triggers) referencing that field and deploy the commented out code
3. Remove any refereces to that field in any flows or workflows
4. Change the field Import the data into the newly blank field

Whew... a huge effort.  Is there a simpler way?  I thought about making another field, then transfering the data to the new field, and updating all the code and references to use the new field.  Still a pain but at least it means i wont have to have any time when the code is broken on live

Would love to hear if others have found a simpler solution

Comment: I've gone with the `"I thought about making another field, then transferring the data to the new field, and updating all the code and references to use the new field. Still a pain but at least it means i wont have to have any time when the code is broken on live"` approach, changing the old field's label to include `(obs.)` and hiding from page layouts

Answer (score 7):

You pretty much hit it on the head. Metadata references will cause you to not be able to change the field on the fly. So, you'll want to probably take these steps:

## Refresh Your Sandbox

If you think your sandbox might be even remotely out of date, replace it with a fresh copy. You're about to embark on a very complicated procedure, and you want the latest information available when you start.

## Create the New Field

Create the new field in your sandbox that will hold the multi-select data. Do not place it on any page layouts or add it to field level security. This comes later.

## Create a New Trigger

Create a trigger that simply copies data from the old field to the new, if the new field hasn't been changed during that trigger's invocation.

## Download All Metadata

Download your entire sandbox organization's metadata in the Force.com IDE using the "select all" option. I realize that this would be a pretty painful experience (10-15 minutes or more is not uncommon). **KEEP A BACKUP OF THIS EXPORT.** You can (almost) always undo everything you're about to do in the next step by copying the backup directly back into the Force.com IDE, thus undoing all changes you've made.

## Search and Replace All Relevant References

Basically, perform the update in all email templates, reports, classes, triggers (except the stop-gap trigger, of course), page layouts, flows, workflow rules, approval processes, etc. I'd recommend doing just one category at a time, making sure you don't miss anything.

Keep track of everything you update. Make sure you swap the old field's security with the new field's security for all profiles. You can generally search and replace without too much effort. Keep in mind, however, that flows and some other elements may be tricky. You might be forced to create a new version of the flow, for example, or you might have to clone an approval process. Keep track of those changes, too, because you'll want to be able to delete or deactivate the originals when you're done.

## Deploy Massive Change Set

Build a change set of all files you modified in the previous step, and be sure to include profiles. Deploy this change to production. If you've been careful enough, everything should go without a hitch. I recommend running a validation first, just to be on the safe side.

## Warn Your Users

While this process will cover all public reports, email templates, and so on, personal reports, list views, and email templates may be affected by the deletion of this field. Allow users some time to migrate to the new field.

## Trigger Data Migration

Export all records (just the ID will do), and run an update against all records. Your trigger will migrate the data for you, and also catch any updates users may have made before you could get to this step.

## Delete Old Field, Trigger, Flows, Etc.

Once everything is done, all that's left is to delete or deactivate any elements that were obsoleted by the migration, such as flow versions, workflows, etc.

---

I have personally done this on a field rename, and it's not a lot of fun, but as long as you're careful, you shouldn't have any major problems that you can't back out of up until the near the end. Doing one big massive push is far easier than trying to do it just one piece at a time, and will minimize downtime.

Comment: ugh, so annoying for what is just changing a regular picklist to a multi-select picklists. Oh well, I guess this is what i'll have to do